# How to change object value type in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, object, types

If I got an object like

```
{"name":12, "name2":15}
```

how can I get those values 12 and 15 to be string values instead of number values ?

It's important to mention I'm not creating this object manually and I cannot just add "" right now, api is sending those values and I need them to be converted to string values.

Thanks.

Comment: The duplicate seems quite harsh since @Perp, I think, is more concerned about how to reach each value than how to convert them... anyway : `for(var key in obj) obj[key] = obj[key].toString();` is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, Boris, I guess that was it :D

Comment: you can convert them downstream as `String(obj[key])` instead of just `obj[key]`